# SQL - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run an insert statement using three sets of data collected by using a union all.

If I run the select statements they work correctly, but if I run the insert statement I get the following error:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6

Must declare the scalar variable "@_EventSessionID".

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 23

Must declare the scalar variable "@_EventSessionID".

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 40

Must declare the scalar variable "@_EventSessionID".

**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.**
```

Declaring the scalar variable is a logical error, but these will be supplied by the application I run this from. The thing I can't figure out is the message depicted in bold.

The last part of the query (including the insert into part) I'm trying to run is the following. Hope anybody can help me out!

```
INSERT INTO _conn_tb_request 
            (_mode, 
             type, 
             _eventsessionid, 
             _task, 
             employeeid, 
             freeintfield_01, 
             freetextfield_01, 
             description, 
             startdate, 
             enddate, 
             freeguidfield_01, 
             freeguidfield_02, 
             freetextfield_03) 
SELECT 0, 
       96, 
       @_EventSessionID, 
       @_EventDescription, 
       res_id, 
       fullname, 
       Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()), 
       'RGA', 
       'RGA gesprek ' 
       + Cast(Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()) AS VARCHAR) 
       + ' - ' + fullname, 
       Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0), 
       Dateadd(mm, 2, Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0)), 
       '3C11435F-598B-4164-8CFD-9A943ED30262', 
       ab.id, 
       ab.freetextfield_02 
FROM   humres hu (nolock) 
       LEFT JOIN absences ab (nolock) 
              ON hu.res_id = ab.empid 
                 AND ab.type = 96 
                 AND ab.freetextfield_01 = 'RGA' 
                 AND ab.freeintfield_01 = Datepart(yyyy, Dateadd(yy, -1, ( 
                                                         Getdate() )) 
                                          ) 
WHERE  ldatindienst < Dateadd(yy, -1, ( Dateadd(dd, 1, ( Dateadd(qq, 
                                                         Datediff(qq, 0, 
                                                         Getdate()), 
                                                                -1) ) 
                                                              ) )) 
       AND emp_type IN ( 'E' ) 
       AND emp_stat = 'A' 
       AND hu.res_id NOT IN (SELECT empid 
                             FROM   absences (nolock) 
                             WHERE  type = 96 
                                    AND freetextfield_01 = 'RGA' 
                                    AND freeintfield_01 = Datepart(yyyy, Getdate 
                                                          ())) 
       AND Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0) < Getdate()
```

Comment: Please use code tags to format code. Select your code, and press Ctrl+k. This makes it easier to read and know what your error is. (:

Comment: Will do! I'm kinda new at posting here :-)

Comment: This syntax seems to be fine: `select 1 where Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0) < Getdate() `, try commenting out the last line and see if it runs, the error may be on an earlier line.

Comment: That's the weird part of it. If I only run the select, it works. Also if I comment it out, it works. It only doesn't work when I run it including the insert statement with that last line.

Comment: Please read up on [`NOLOCK`](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/), [lazy shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) and [varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: Your SELECT has 14 columns while your INSERT only specifies 13

Comment: Indeed, I corrected that one, after that I'm still having the error

Comment: just out of my curiosity am asking Why u need the last line? that will fail only on the first day of the year is that u want? just curious

Answer (score 0):

Please see line 24  Cast(Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()) AS VARCHAR). 
Problems with brackets.

Comment: That part runs ok actually. It's the  AND Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0) < Getdate() part which is giving the trouble in my code